# SDL Error. OpenGL active, use SDL_GL_SwapBuffers()

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl, sdl

I am using SDL & C++ to create a game, but whenever I try to render a bitmap I get an error saying during runtime 'OpenGL active, use SDL_GL_SwapBuffers().' But the thing is, I am using SDL_GL_SwapBuffers(). Here is the code:

The drawing function:

```
bool d2Sprite::Draw(SDL_Surface *dest, SDL_Surface *src, int x, int y)
{
if(dest == NULL || src == NULL)
{
    cout << "Unable draw sprite! " << SDL_GetError() << endl;
    return false;
}

SDL_Rect destR;
destR.x = x;
destR.y = y;

SDL_BlitSurface(src, NULL, dest, &destR);

return true;
}
```

The game loop:
    void d2Main::GameLoop()
    {
    cout << "Game loop running!" << endl;

```
d2Main::Load();
while(d2Main::gameRunning)
{
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        d2Main::HandleEvents(&event);
    }

    d2Main::Update();

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPushMatrix();

    d2Main::Render();
    SDL_UpdateRect(screen, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    glPopMatrix();
    SDL_GL_SwapBuffers(); // <-- I AM USING IT
    SDL_Delay(0.8);
}

SDL_Quit();
}
```

Comment: Try commenting out `SDL_UpdateRect(screen, 0, 0, 0, 0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for the error message in the SDL source:

http://svn.libsdl.org/tags/SDL/release-1.2.10/src/video/SDL_video.c

It occurs here:

```
void SDL_UpdateRects (SDL_Surface *screen, int numrects, SDL_Rect *rects)
{
    int i;
    SDL_VideoDevice *video = current_video;
    SDL_VideoDevice *this = current_video;

    if ( (screen->flags & (SDL_OPENGL | SDL_OPENGLBLIT)) == SDL_OPENGL ) {
        SDL_SetError("OpenGL active, use SDL_GL_SwapBuffers()");
        return;
    }

    //...
```

As such, you probably need to get rid of your call to `SDL_UpdateRects` - it's not supported when you're using OpenGL unless you're using the `SDL_OPENGLBLIT` flag. As an alternative, therefore, you could set the flag. However, note that AFAIK it's (a) slower and (b) no longer officially supported.